# How to select the <p:dataTable> by CSS?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

First I was using `<h:dataTable>` and I was OK with this but after then I needed some more functionality, So I started using Primefaces and used its `<p:dataTable>`. Everything is going fine but the CSS that I applied on tables stopped woking. Then I found that `<p:dataTable>` is first creating a `<div>` and then inside the `<div>`, it is creating a `<table>`.

```
 <div id="tcform:tclist" .......>
       <table role="grid">....</table>
 </div>
```

But `<h:dataTable>` creates just HTML `<table>`. Now I want to know how can I get table's id or is there any solution that I can access that table. I also want to know that Why `<h:dataTable>` and `<p:dataTable>` differs from each other.

Comment: if you do prependId="false" on your form you can access the table like this `#tclist.ui-datatable table {....}` also if you want access to tr for example you can do `#tclist tr{...}` if you got form prepeneded I guess you can try  `#tcform:tclist tr{...}` or `#tcform\\:tclist tr{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to style tables in a generic manner, just change the CSS selectors accordingly.  The `<table>` of `<p:dataTable>` is selectable by the `ui-datatable` class.

```css
.ui-datatable td {
    background: pink;
}
```

If you want to style only a specific table in a specific manner, rather give it a classname so that you can select by the classname instead of by ID.

E.g.

```html
<p:dataTable styleClass="foo">
```

is overrideable by `.ui-datatable.foo {}`. E.g.

```css
.ui-datatable.foo td {
    background: hotpink;
}
```

Comment: for this should i do prependId="false" ?

Comment: No, you're not selecting by ID here. Selecting by ID makes usually only sense for main layout components which is shared across the entire site, such as header/menu/content/footer. They are usually not in a form or table or so.

Comment: Can I get the HTML <table> (created by primefaces DataTable)  by doing this in my javascript file-> ('ui-datatable').dataTable({.....});