# Primefaces Datatable - Change font size

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, resize

I was wondering if it possible to make the font size of column headers and body smaller of p:datatable?

I am not sure how to do this with css.

Comment: this might help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194819/how-to-select-the-pdatatable-by-css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

apply the below style to the p:dataTable

```
style="font-size:8px;"
```

(or)

override the styleclass the default value of the font-size is 12px;

```
<style>
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 8px;
}
</style>
```

Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: Thanks! However when i try the second technique, everything becomes smaller. How can i make it to be just the datatable, using the style tags rather than inline?

Comment: the first approach is working or not?

Comment: beacause of ui-widget styleclass for all the components.

Comment: yes. Yeah I understand that ui-widget styles everything. Just wondering if i can only style the datatable?

Comment: `!important` is being abused here. This is not the right/recommended way. Please learn CSS cascading rules and revise your answer. If posted right, I'll remove the downvote. And no, using `style` is a poor practice and thus also not recommended.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your Recommendation